# Compiling on a mac: What does it mean if my compiler fails a sanity check?

Tags: macos, gcc

I'm trying to install some astronomy packages, specifically cfitsio.  Using both the "built-in" mac gcc/g++ compilers and the HPC compilers, I get the following errors:

```
configure: error: C preprocessor "/usr/local/bin/g++" fails sanity check
configure: error: C preprocessor "/usr/bin/g++" fails sanity check



$ /usr/local/bin/g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 4.8.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.


$ /usr/bin/g++ --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.2
Thread model: posix
```

Looking at `config.log`, as suggested, is rather unrevealing:

```
configure:3409: checking how to run the C preprocessor
configure:3479: result: /usr/local/bin/g++
configure:3499: /usr/local/bin/g++  conftest.c
conftest.c:14:8: error: 'Syntax' does not name a type
        Syntax error
        ^
```

My install commands look like:

```
CPP=/usr/local/bin/g++ CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++ CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc CFLAGS="-arch x86_64 -g -O2" ./configure
CPP=/usr/bin/g++ CXX=/usr/bin/g++ CC=/usr/bin/gcc CFLAGS="-arch x86_64 -g -O2" ./configure
```

Googling has so far yielded no fruitful results.  What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: If it fails a sanity check? It's insane ;-)

Comment: Can you amend your question to list the contents of `conftest.c` (particularly around line 14)? I think your autoconfigure script may actually be to blame here.

Comment: CPP is not meant to be your C++ compiler. It is meant to be your preprocessor. These are two different things. g++ is not a preprocessor, it's a compiler. You cannot use it as a preprocessor without additional arguments. Find out what these arguments are.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: it does not exist after I run `./configure` - any tips on how I can keep it around?  @n.m.: Very good to know, I had always wondered why there are both `CXX` and `CPP` in `configure`.  However, I have no idea where to find out what preprocessor arguments are needed - nothing is referred to in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer was identified by @n.m. in the comments: The environmental variable `CPP` was incorrectly set to point to `g++`, which of course will not work.  `cpp` is the name of the C precompiler on my system.