# Compile GCC 7 : error: C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check

Tags: windows, gcc, mingw-w64

Trying to build GCC 7.1.0 from source. This is not my first time and it used to work in past GCC releases.

```
../configure --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 \
 --prefix=/c/mingw64 --with-sysroot=/c/mingw64 \
 --with-gmp=/c/mingw64/gmp --with-mpfr=/c/mingw64/mpfr --with-mpc=/c/mingw64/mpc \
 --with-isl=/c/mingw64/isl \
 --disable-nls --disable-multilib --disable-libstdcxx-pch --disable-shared \
 --disable-win32-registry --disable-libstdcxx-debug --disable-libstdcxx-verbose \
 --with-tune=haswell --enable-lto --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++ \
 --enable-libstdcxx-time --enable-threads=win32 --enable-libatomic --enable-fully-dynamic-string
```

Error

```
checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... /lib/cpp
configure: error: in `/c/mingw64/src/build/gcc':
configure: error: C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details.
make[2]: *** [Makefile:4309: configure-stage2-gcc] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/c/mingw64/src/build'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:20550: stage2-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/c/mingw64/src/build'
make: *** [Makefile:936: all] Error 2
```

Complete config.log: https://pastebin.com/raw/mEeJHCuK

Note that I `/lib/cpp` never exists.

I did some google search and tried every suggestions, including:

- `CXX=/c/mingw/bin/g++` (likewise to `CC` and `CPP`)
- Replace all occurances of `/lib/cpp` in `gcc-7.1.0/gcc/configure` with `/c/mingw/bin/g++`. Which gave me:

```
    conftest.c:14:8: error: 'Syntax' does not name a type
            Syntax error
            ^
```

(^ is similar to [Compiling on a mac: What does it mean if my compiler fails a sanity check?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22048505/compiling-on-a-mac-what-does-it-mean-if-my-compiler-fails-a-sanity-check))

There was an old (critical) bug that seems related at https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-bugs/2015-10/msg00604.html , but no update.

Comment: Same issue here. It's caused by `checking how to run the C++ preprocessor` (see your config.log a few lines above the `/lib/cpp` failure). It can't find `limits.h` there for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CPP` should not point to `g++`; `CPP` is the C preprocessor, so make it point to the C preprocessor:

```
CPP=/c/mingw/bin/cpp
```

This is mentioned on the question you linked to.

Comment: Used your solution, but also need to replace all occurrences of "/lib/cpp" with "/c/mingw/bin/cpp" in src/gcc/configure. Marking your post as answer nonetheless.

Comment: @JohnLondon: Okay sounds like the configure script is buggy tbh